# How do I specify an x date coordinate on geom_ text function on R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to put a text on an especific point in an histogram plot

```
ggplot(ECOBICI2) + 
aes(x = Fecha_Arribo) + 
geom_histogram(binwidth = 1) +
geom_text(aes(x = 2020-03-24), y = 12000, label = "Inicio de cierre de actividades")   +
labs(x = "Dia", y = "Viajes Por Día") +
theme_classic()
```

It gives me this error
Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only

Fecha_Arribo are dates

I tried to put an as.Date()

```
ggplot(ECOBICI2) + 
aes(x = Fecha_Arribo) + 
geom_histogram(binwidth = 1) +
geom_text(aes(x = as.Date(2020-03-24, "%Y/%m/%d"), y = 12000, label = "Inicio de cierre de actividades")   +
labs(x = "Dia", y = "Viajes Por Día") +
theme_classic()
```

Then it gives me this error
Error in charToDate(x) :
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @heds1 you have to specify the proper format for data using quotes and the structure of year, month and day so that the `as.Date()` function can recognize it as date. Another point is that you must specify the `x`,`y` and `label` values inside the `aes()` option for `geom_text()`. I have replicated a example for you using some dummy data. For sure in your real data you can change the values in `geom_text()` to obtain the desired plot. Here the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data
df <- data.frame(Fecha_Arribo=sample(seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'),
                                         as.Date('2020-10-01'),
                                         by='1 day'),500,replace = T))
```

Next the code for plot, I have also added a vertical line if you want to consider that option in your plot:

```
#Plot
ggplot(df,aes(x=Fecha_Arribo))+
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1) +
  geom_text(aes(x = as.Date('2020-03-24'),y=8,label = "Inicio de cierre de actividades"))+
  geom_vline(xintercept = as.Date('2020-03-24'),lty='dashed')+
  labs(x = "Dia", y = "Viajes Por Día") +
  theme_classic()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two things wrong here. Firstly, your `format` argument to `as.Date` does not match the format that you supply; you're telling it to parse a date delimited with forward slashes "/", but the date object that you supply is delimited by hyphens "-". Secondly, you're passing the date as a variable (with an impossible name, i.e., 2020-03-24), rather than as a string.

So, pass the date as a string, and supply the correct `format` argument to `as.Date`, e.g.:

```
as.Date('2020-03-24', '%Y-%m-%d')
```